# Using decltype like typedef

Tags: c++, c++11

Experimenting with `decltype` to be used in place of a `typedef` or `auto` keywords whenever deemed necessary. Some of them ( stl and user function ) works  however it doesn't work directly with a user defined object. Please I need an explanation here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct foo {
    void operator=(const int a ) { val_ =a;}
    int get() const { return val_;}
  private:
    int val_;
}; 

ostream& operator << (ostream& os, foo f )
{
    os << f.get();
    return os;
}

foo func()
{
    foo a;
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    vector<foo> foos;
    decltype(foos) b; //works

    decltype(foo);//  don't work  - says - error C3553: decltype expects an expression not a type

    decltype(func()) a; //works
    a = 100;

    std::cout << a << " \n";
}
```

**EDITED**

```
vector<foo> foos;
decltype(foos) b; //works :tested with vc++ compiler


decltype(vector<foo>) b; //fails
```

Comment: What isn't clear about the error? `foo` isn't a valid expression

Comment: as error explain, `decltype` expects expression not type, so `decltype(foo())` works whereas `decltype(int)` wont.

Comment: @StoryTeller: so STL containers are treated as expressions?

Comment: also `decltype(int{})` is an expression and works; and `decltype(std::vector<foo>)` doesn't work.

Comment: in addition `type;` is invalid, `type var_name;` would be valid.

Comment: @ark1974 this has nothing to do with standard containers. `decltype(vector<int>)` would fail just the same.

Comment: @max66: Thanks . `decltype(foo{})` works now.

Comment: Maybe you are a little bit confused between [decltype](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) and [declval](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval)?

Comment: @ark1974 - No, type names aren't expressions. `foos` is the name of an object, which can be an expression... `vector<foo>` isn't an expression either

Comment: `foo` is already a type.

Comment: @Quentin: `decltype(vector<int>)` compiles and runs fine tho on http://rextester.com. That's my confusion with STL.

Comment: @ark1974 [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/31dded7653bde18f). If it does, that's a bug in your compiler.

Comment: @ark1974 - "compiles and runs fine" [fake news](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d3a25f0bc6bd11bf).

Comment: I tested on http://rextester.com with VC++ , and it runs . YEah fails in clang tho. Just tested. So its a bug. Thanks everyone

Comment: @ark1974 I get "error C3553: decltype expects an expression not a type".

Comment: @ark1974 [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/) with VC++ rejects `decltype(std::vector<int>)` for the exactly same reason.

Comment: @DeanSeo : Have you check with vector<foo> foos;? it works in vc++.

Comment: @ark1974 Yes, but that works not only in VC++, but also **gcc** and **clang**.

Answer (score 1):

`decltype` is equivalent to the declaration type of its object operand(or a dummy object). So you feed it with an object and get the class at compile time. Since the result is a type, you can use it wherever a `typename` is expected. You can't feed it with a type.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype